# Unknown argument -model in stanford nlp

Tags: stanford-nlp

When I am trying to build PTB format dataset with the following command, I am getting a message like 'Unknown argument -model'. Why am I getting this message? Is there something wrong with the command?

```
java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.BuildBinarizedDataset -model edu/stanford/nlp/models/sentiment/sentiment.ser.gz -input train.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-sentimentModel` flag rather than `-model`.

Comment: Is there any difference between sentimentModel and model? What if I build the binarized set without giving -model parameter?

Comment: This program has no `model` parameter :) If you don't give a `-sentimentModel` parameter, the trees will be marked as having unknown sentiment. See https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/sentiment/BuildBinarizedDataset.java#L203

Comment: If I use -sentimentModel as sentiment.ser.gz, my sentences are marked with a different sentiment tag as compared to the training set.For ex: if I use 1 for negative,2 for neutral and 3 for positive, in the PTB dataset obtained, few sentences are marked with 0 which I have never used in the training set. How is this possible?

Comment: There's no guarantee that your model will be able to exactly reproduce the labels of the training set. In fact, if it were able to do so I'd worry that the model might have [overfit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). That being said, if there are a lot of errors this might be evidence that the original model wasn't trained well (i.e., long enough, with the right parameters, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. Which sentimentModel should I use to build the binarized set? Is it sentiment.ser.gz or englishPCFG.ser.gz?

Comment: Use `sentiment.ser.gz`, or whatever file is the result of training a `SentimentModel`. `englishPCFG` is a constituency parsing model (not a sentiment model), the result of training `LexicalizedParser`.